# The k8s java pod cpu is full and the business is normal

Tags: kubernetes, cpu

When I use command `kubectl top pods`, the target pods show:

```
xxx-857c847496-6bkj5                           819m         6523Mi
xxx-857c847496-7r2l5                           945m         6356Mi
```

When I enter the container and use the `top` command, it shows that the CPU is full

```
PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU  %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND                                                                                                             
  7 root      20   0   26.2g   4.3g  16592 S  125%   3.4 169:22.07 java
```

It's so weird that the pod CPU usage seen on the physical machine is so different from inside the container. So why?

The deployment is

```html
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  annotations: {}
  labels:
    app: xxx
    version: v1
  name: xxx
  namespace: admin
spec:
  progressDeadlineSeconds: 600
  replicas: 6
  revisionHistoryLimit: 10
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: xxx
      version: v1
  strategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 50%
      maxUnavailable: 50%
    type: RollingUpdate
  template:
    metadata:
      annotations:
        kubectl.kubernetes.io/restartedAt: '2022-10-04T10:15:14+08:00'
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        app: xxx
        version: v1
    spec:
      affinity:
        podAntiAffinity:
          requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
            - labelSelector:
                matchLabels:
                  app: xxx
              topologyKey: kubernetes.io/hostname
      containers:
        - env:
            - name: JAVA_ARGS
              value: >-
                -Xms1G -Xmx4G -XX:NewRatio=1 -XX:+UseContainerSupport
                -XX:MaxRAMPercentage=75.0
                -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
                -Dlog4j2.formatMsgNoLookups=true
          image: '192.168.10.42/xxx/xxx:03f1006'
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          livenessProbe:
            failureThreshold: 10
            httpGet:
              path: /actuator/health/liveness
              port: 53387
              scheme: HTTP
            initialDelaySeconds: 30
            periodSeconds: 10
            successThreshold: 1
            timeoutSeconds: 2
          name: xxx
          ports:
            - containerPort: 47038
              protocol: TCP
            - containerPort: 53387
              protocol: TCP
          readinessProbe:
            failureThreshold: 10
            httpGet:
              path: /actuator/health/readiness
              port: 53387
              scheme: HTTP
            initialDelaySeconds: 30
            periodSeconds: 10
            successThreshold: 1
            timeoutSeconds: 2
          resources:
            limits:
              cpu: '8'
              memory: 8Gi
            requests:
              cpu: '3'
              memory: 5000Mi
          terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
          terminationMessagePolicy: File
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /opt/logs
              name: xxx-logs-volume
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: harborsecret
      restartPolicy: Always
      schedulerName: default-scheduler
      securityContext: {}
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
      tolerations:
        - effect: NoSchedule
          key: tag
          operator: Equal
          value: scm-only
      volumes:
        - name: xxx-logs-volume
          nfs:
            path: /opt/nfs_k8s_logs/scm/xxx
            server: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
status:
  availableReplicas: 5
  conditions:
    - lastTransitionTime: '2022-09-26T14:30:45Z'
      lastUpdateTime: '2022-09-26T14:30:45Z'
      message: Deployment has minimum availability.
      reason: MinimumReplicasAvailable
      status: 'True'
      type: Available
    - lastTransitionTime: '2022-07-04T09:11:19Z'
      lastUpdateTime: '2022-10-13T11:18:52Z'
      message: ReplicaSet "xxx-766854789f" is progressing.
      reason: ReplicaSetUpdated
      status: 'True'
      type: Progressing
  observedGeneration: 83
  readyReplicas: 6
  replicas: 6
  unavailableReplicas: 1
  updatedReplicas: 6
```

Comment: Please show the pod/deployment manifest

Comment: i have show the deployment manifest,thank you

Comment: %CPU -- CPU Usage : The percentage of your CPU that is being used by the process. By default, top displays this as a percentage of a single CPU. On multi-core systems, you can have percentages that are greater than 100%. For example, if 3 cores are at 60% use, top will show a CPU use of 180%. You can toggle this behavior by hitting `Shift+i` while top is running to show the overall percentage of available CPUs in use.